# How to change default membership provider value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, membership, static-members

I have declare multiple membership provider in web.config

```
<membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15" defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"  />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />        
    <add name="Reset_Pass" connectionStringName="AspNetDB" applicationName="/" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="100000" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="100000" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" passwordFormat="Hashed" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" type="SiteMemberShipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

But when i call following , Membership is assign with value of default provider.

```
public static MembershipUser GetUserInfoByUserName(string username)
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
            return user;
        }
```

when I monitor value on Membership value it set value of defaultProvider

[image]

How can I change membership provider value to "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider".

Comment: Did you try to change `defaultProvider` attribute value to `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider`? From code you do it with `var provider = Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"];`

Comment: Yes but I do not want to do that. because current code is using it.

Comment: "that" what? Choose from code or choose via attribute? You have to pick one of them...